# Admob CTR - where to check it?

Tags: admob

I am interested to check my admob CTR, but I cannot find it anywhere. Search in G told me about developer console, but I didn't see any console in Admob interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Monetize tab. The table of data has a column labelled `Impression CTR`